# Control over clang-format Objective-C block argument line breaks

Tags: objective-c, clang-format

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent clang-format from adding line breaks when there is a block as an argument.

For example, I want this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(500 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"here");
});
```

Not this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(500 * NSEC_PER_SEC)),
               dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^{
                 NSLog(@"here");
               });
```

To throw a wrench in things, I also want multiple block arguments to be broken up like:

```
[self method:argument success:^(NSString* result) {
    // Do stuff
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    // Do other stuff
}
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? Is it even possible with clang-format?

My [.clang-format](https://gist.github.com/ericreid/b9418205c1fbc40ef301)

Comment: I'm looking for this as well.